# Java error: constructor cannot be applied to given types?

Tags: java

I have to ask the user to input the dimensions of two boxes then calulate the surface area and volume of two boxes. I am done with everything but i keep getting the error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types:

My main class BoxCalc:

```
package boxcalc;

import cs1.Keyboard;
public class BoxCalc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int width, length, height, volume1, volume2, surfacearea1, surfacearea2;

        Box b1 = new Box();
        Box b2 = new Box();

    b1.getClass();
    b2.getClass();

    // Ask the user the demensions for Box 1.
    System.out.println ("Box 1");
    System.out.print ("Enter a value for the height of Box 1: ");
    height = Keyboard.readInt();
    System.out.println ("Enter a value for the length of Box 1: ");
    length = Keyboard.readInt();
    System.out.println ("Enter a value for the width of Box 1: ");
    width = Keyboard.readInt();

    // Calulating the volume and the surface area of Box 1.
    volume1 = width*height*length;
    surfacearea2 = (2*(length * height))+(2 *(length * width))+
            (2*(width*height));

    // Ask the user the demensions for Box 2.
    System.out.println ("Box 2");
    System.out.print ("Enter a value for the height of Box 2: ");
    height = Keyboard.readInt();
    System.out.println ("Enter a value for the length of Box 2: ");
    length = Keyboard.readInt();
    System.out.println ("Enter a value for the width of Box 2: ");
    width = Keyboard.readInt();

    // Calulating the volume and the surface area of Box 2.
    volume2 = width*height*length;
    surfacearea2 = (2*(length * height))+(2 *(length * width))+
            (2*(width*height));

    // Determain which Box has greater volume.
    if (volume1 > volume2)
    {
        System.out.println("Box 1's volume is greater!");
    }
    else
        if(volume2 > volume1)
        {
        System.out.println("Box 2's volume is greater!");
        }
    if(volume1 == volume2)
    {
        System.out.println("Box 1's volume is same as Box 2's!");
    }

    // Display all the information.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(b1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(b2);
    }
}
```

My class Box:

```
package boxcalc;

public class Box 
{
    private int width, length, height, volume, surfacearea;


    // Defining the width, length, and height.
       public Box (int boxwidth, int boxlength, int boxheight)
        {
            width = boxwidth;
            length = boxlength;
           height = boxheight;
       }


      // Method to calulate the volume.
       public void findVolume(int volume)
      {
           volume = length * height * width;
     }

        // Method to calulate the surface area.
      public void findSurfaceArea(int surfacearea)
    {
          surfacearea = (2*(length * height))+(2 *(length * width))+
                  (2*(width*height));
       }

        // Use toString method to display all the info above.
        public String toString()
        {
        return ("Length: " + length + "\n" + "Width: " + width + "\n" + 
                "Height: " + height + "\n" + "Volume: " + volume +"\n" + 
                "Surface area: " + surfacearea + "\n");
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, your program isn't object-oriented in the slightest.

There was no point in posting your `Box` class, as your main program doesn't make use of it in any significant way.

You're determining which box is bigger in a structured programming manner, by declaring enough variables in main to do all of the logic.

You should get all the dimensions for `box1`, then do this:

```
Box b1 = new Box(width, height, length);
```

Then do the same for `box2`, and again:

```
Box b2 = new Box(width,height,length);
```

Then, in your `if` statements, instead of `volume1 > volume2`, you should instead be doing something more like this:

```
if(b1.getVolume() > b2.getVolume())
```

Where `getVolume()` should be a method of your `Box` class that looks like this:

```
public int getVolume() {
    return volume;
}
```

(Although, best practices might say don't even include a `volume` variable in the `Box` class, and simple do `return (width * height * length);`

The same principles should be applied to other aspects of your program.

As a note, by doing it this way, your main program only needs 3 `int` variables: `width`, `height`, `length`.  Once you send `b1`'s dimension into the constructor, the `b1` variables knows its dimensions, and you can reuse these variables for taking in `b2`'s dimensions.  You don't need `volume1`, `volume2`, `surfacearea1`, or `surfacearea2` variables, because a complete `Box` class would allow you to get these `Box` properties via `getVolume()` and `getSurfaceArea()`.

Answer (score 2):

your box constructor:

```
public Box (int boxwidth, int boxlength, int boxheight)
    {
        width = boxwidth;
        length = boxlength;
       height = boxheight;
   }
```

but you creating box object with no parameter:

```
Box b1 = new Box();
Box b2 = new Box();
```

it should be:

after you ask user for the dimension of box 1, put this:

```
    Box b1 = new Box(width, length, height);
```

after you ask user for the dimension of box 2, put this:

```
    Box b2 = new Box(width, length, height);
```

Comment: i did that but it give me a different error. Like ".class expected"

Comment: Yeah i get that. I am not a that good at programmimg. Is that the only thing i m doing wrong or is there anything else.

Comment: you have many other errors. please refer to @nhgrif answer below

Comment: @user3015601 i think you dont need this line: b1.getClass(); b2.getClass();

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Box constructor with *no* parameters: `Box b1 = new Box();`, and in the class itself it is defined as requiring to have multiple (three) numeric parameters: `public Box (int boxwidth, int boxlength, int boxheight)`. So the compiler is rightfully complaining that something is amiss.

### Possible Solutions:

1. When you call the constructor, pass in 3 numbers that make sense. **Edit**: and do this **after** the user has entered valid data.
2. Or give Box a default constructor that takes no parameters and sets its fields to some default values.

Comment: Thanks! can u give an example. sorry

Comment: the user will be entering the values. not me

Comment: @user3015601: then the obvious solution is to hold off constructing your Box objects until **after** the user enters their values. Then use their entered values to construct the Box objects.